# Alt+Tab and Super+Tab not working after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, gnome-shell

I just upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 after 17.04 went out of support.

After the reboot finalizing the upgrade the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> stopped working.

However, the "Switch Application Windows" Hotkey keeps working, and, if I keep the switcher open by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I can then switch between Applications using <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I already tried resetting those settings and setting the shortcuts using the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward  "['<Alt><Shift>Tab', '<Super><Shift>Tab']"
```

I also switched these around a bit to experiment but couldn't get it to work.

But as of now this is pretty annoying.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check in Preferences -> devices -> keyboard ?

Comment: Yes. Whatever I put in there doesn't change the behavior, also no errors related in syslog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update:

You can try reloading Gnome via <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, pressing <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Thanks to [Rob Hendricks](https://askubuntu.com/users/944621/rob-hendricks) for this hint.

---

## Original Answer

Interestingly, after issuing the above commands, a reboot fixed it, when reloading the desktop environment didn't.

So for anyone encountering this, set your preferred settings using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward  "['<Alt><Shift>Tab', '<Super><Shift>Tab']"
```

And reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by FatalMerlin worked great. You can also do an ‘alt-f2’ followed by ‘r’ and enter to restart gnome without the reboot...

Comment: Thanks Rob! I'll add that to my answer, if you don't mind :)
Also welcome to the StackExchange community!

Comment: Please do :)

Been here for a while :) You guys are usually so great that I don't need to add ;)